# tiom pri... kiel pri...

Tags: grammar

Ĉu estas gramatike ĝusta la jena frazo el Tekstaro (Artikoloj el Monato)?:

> Temas eĉ ne tiom pri la enlitaj momentoj, kiel pri ties prezento.

Ĉu ne devas nepre esti *kiom pri* anstataŭ *kiel pri*?

Comment: Bona demando! Mi ankaux scivolas pri tio. Mi rimarkis ke kiel estas uzata por cxiaj tiaj ligoj, be nur por referi al agadverboj sed ankaux kvanto, tempo, adjektivoj/trajtoj ktp

Answer (score 3):

"Tiom" estas emfaza formo de "tiel". Mi ne certas ĉu mi mem vortumus la frazon en tiu maniero, sed ĝi ŝajnas bona laŭ mi.

Comment: Nome "tiom" = "tiel multe". Tamen "kiom" anst. "kiel" eblas.